# Android Contacts Content Provider

Tags: android, contacts, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to create application to communicate. I show contacts list from android contacts book. How can I indicate that contact installed my application ( like Viber does) ? Do I need creating own table in db with contacts's copy or Contacts ContentProvider can help me?

[image: viber example]

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code :

Write these lines to fetch contacts :

```
     Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK, ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_CONTACT);
 }
```

And override this method  :

```
@Override public void onActivityResult(int reqCode, int resultCode, Intent data){ super.onActivityResult(reqCode, resultCode, data);

switch(reqCode)
{
   case (PICK_CONTACT):
     if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK)
     {
         Uri contactData = data.getData();
         Cursor c = managedQuery(contactData, null, null, null, null);
      if (c.moveToFirst())
      {
      String id = c.getString(c.getColumnIndexOrThrow(ContactsContract.Contacts._ID));

      String hasPhone =
      c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.Contacts.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER));

      if (hasPhone.equalsIgnoreCase("1")) 
      {
     Cursor phones = getContentResolver().query(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTENT_URI,null, 
      ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.CONTACT_ID +" = "+ id,null, null);
        phones.moveToFirst();
        String cNumber = phones.getString(phones.getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.CommonDataKinds.Phone.NUMBER));
       // Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), cNumber, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        setCn(cNumber);
      }
     }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank for reply. But i need list of contacts in my app. For this purpose i use content provider wich returns cursor. But Contact.Content_uri returns cursor without additional field and Data.content_uri returns duplicates

Comment: You can handle duplicate contacts

Comment: Yes i can. For this i need to store contacts somewhere. I didnt find solution to read contacts with phones and additional data from contentprovider using one query

Comment: Could you post what and how you did this? Did you make two queries?